# Need explanation for time complexity analysis of iterative program

Tags: data-structures

What is the time complexity of the following iterative program?

```
void function(int n) {
    int count = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++) 
            if (j%i == 0) 
            { 
                for (int k=0; k<j; k++) 
                    printf("*"); 
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(n * n * n^2) making complexity for the three loops is O(n^4).

When i = 5,

This implies total complexity,

```
for (int j=5; j< 25; j++)  
     if (j%i == 0) // runs O(i) times
     {
      // runs j times when j = 5, 10, 15, 20
            for (int k=0; k<j; k++) {
                printf("*"); // runs j times when j =  5(1 + 2 + 3+ 4)
               // runs  j times which is i*i*(i*(i-1)/2) times
               // runs i^4 times
            }
     }
```

this implies total complexity is O(n^4).
Remember that big-O notation is used to give an upper bound on the run-time of a piece of code, so saying that the run-time is O(n5) if the run-time is actually O(n4) isn't wrong; it's just not tight.

Comment: Could you explain it furthermore... As I saw this example in geeksforgeeks there the time complexity of the above program is given  O(n^5). But I want to know the explanation..

Comment: For more information, please go to "problem 7" in this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithms-set-5-practice-problems/

Comment: You're just looking at one example I guess. The complexity should be O(n^5) as suggested by the OP

Comment: @AndrewScott if you started from inner most loop and work your way to the outermost loop you'll only get  theta(i^3) work. Altogether making O(N^4).

Comment: @AndrewScott I got the explanation i.e outer (i) loop executes "n" times, inner (j) loop executes "n-1" times and innermost (k) loop executes "n*(n*(n-1)/2) times for any "n" value. Therefore time complexity is n*(n-1)*n*(n*(n-1)/2) i.e, O(n^5)